# Looking for the smoking count or rate per census tract in New York State

Tags: medical, census

It seems like this only exists at the county level here - [PA-Percentage-of-Cigarette-Smoking-Among-Adults](https://health.data.ny.gov/Health/PA-Percentage-of-Cigarette-Smoking-Among-Adults-Ma/d4y4-r7hb)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to be a bummer, but I don't think it exists.

For anything at census tract level you (almost always) need to go to either the SF1 files or the ACS files from census.gov. SF1 are just demographics, ACS are a little more of the 'other' stuff.

The 5 year survey has the highest granularity.

http://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/summary_file/2010/documentation/5_year/ACS_2006-2010_SF_Tech_Doc.pdf

Scroll to the data dictionary toward the bottom to see what you can get. I didn't read the whole thing but did a Ctrl+F for 'smok' and had zero results.

I think what you have is about the closest you will find.

Comment: Before someone down votes me for not answering the question- No solution exists is an answer, so prove me wrong before you fire that -1

Comment: That's generally not how stackexchange works from my experience. I would have answered the same. The best data that exists publicly would likely be from the BRFSS at the county level.

Comment: Not how it's supposed to, but every now and again someone gets a little trigger happy. Never happened to me, but I've seen it done to others.

Answer (score 1):

Rate of smoking is not a question asked on the American Community Survey, or, as far as I know, in any US Census Bureau instrument. [Here's a page from the US Census Bureau](http://www.census.gov/topics/health.html) outlining the health topics they cover. The top level categories they use to organize it are:

- Disability
- Expenses & Investments
- Fertility
- Health Insurance
- HIV/AIDS
- Small Area Health Insurance Estimates

(Not all of these are part of the ACS, and those which aren't won't be published to the census tract level. Even the "Small area" health insurance estimates only go down to counties.)

Generally, health statistics are rarely tabulated at small geographies like census tracts because of concerns of publishing personally identifiable information, as well as, probably, the cost of data collection at that scale.